# Image spliting and stitching

Tags: rendering, add-on, camera

Hi I'm trying to render out a 12 image split render and wanted to know if there is a way to do it on 2.93 automatically?
I saw an addon called "Camera-Cropper-Splitter-b2.7x" but there isn't a recent build for it.

Comment: It would be possible to write a Python script to do this at the push of a button, but you would have to add a bunch of details to your question. For instance, when you say 12 images do you mean 12 images that are created by Blender as renders or do you mean 12 images that are imported from elsewhere?  What does your 'split render' look like?  Is it a 3x4 grid, or a 4x3 grid, or something else and how do you identify which image goes in which slot in the split?  Please update your question with details like this.

Comment: Hi im referring to a 3x4 grid made from renders in blender, I have one image which I would like to split to a grid of 3x4 to later stitch for a  high resolution image